# How to prove the tautology $\neg\exists x\varphi\leftrightarrow \forall x\neg \varphi$ according to Halbeisen and Krapf's book

Tags: reference-request, first-order-logic, proof-theory

I'm studying some basic features of Proof Theory in the recent "Gödel's Theorems and Zermelo's Axioms", by Halbeisen and Krapf. In this book, the authors introduce a list of logical axioms in order to present a Hilbert Style system for formalized proofs (the relevant part is available [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=opsDEAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR1&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

However, there are no exemples showing how to use these axioms (and the two inference rules: Modus Ponens and Generalization) in order to prove tautologies with quantifiers, such as the one stated in the title: $\vdash\neg\exists x\varphi\leftrightarrow \forall x\neg \varphi$, which is an abbreviation for $\vdash \neg\exists x \varphi\to\forall x\neg\varphi$ *and* $\vdash \forall x\neg\varphi\to \neg\exists x\varphi$.

I'm aware of some theorems that probably would make this task easier, such as the Deduction Theorem and some methods of proof, like contradiction, contrapositive, etc. However, even with these tools I'm not able to translate my *semantical* intuition to this formal context.

Thus, I would like to ask for hints regarding this tautology or references in which I could find a few examples of the same nature.

Comment: It may help to prove the following taut (pag.17): $(\varphi \to \psi) \to ((\varphi \to \lnot \psi) \to \lnot \varphi)$

Comment: For the left-to-right part, with it (and Deduction Th) you have to start with temporary assumption $\varphi$ and deduce (by DT) $\lnot \exists x \varphi \vdash \varphi \to \lnot \exists x \varphi$. With axiom: $\vdash \varphi \to \exists x \varphi$ by the formula above, we conclude with $\lnot \varphi$. The conclusion follows by Generalization.

Comment: Got it! Since $A\to (B\to A)$ is an axiom, DT gives the first assertion with $A:=\neg \exists x\varphi$ and $B:=\varphi$. Then the hint and two applications of Modus Ponens give $\neg\varphi$. Thank you.